# main verb+ verb-ed versus main verb + that

Tags: sentence-construction

How correct is the word "identified" in the sentence below? Does the word "identified" need "that were" before to be a complete dependent sentence? What are the grammar rules at use in similar sentence structures?

> They take any faults identified in themselves and put them onto others

Answer (score 1):

In English it is common to omit determiners in certain contexts.

For example:

- Birds native to England include...
- Birds *that are* native to England include...
- I love cakes coated with icing and sprinkles.
- I love cakes *that are* coated with icing and sprinkles.

Your example is just as correct with, or without "*that were*".

Answer (score 1):

> *They take any faults* [*identified in themselves*] *and put them onto others*.

It's fine, and it doesn't need "that were" to be grammatical or meaningful.

The bracketed element is a past-participial clause modifying "faults".

Participial clauses functioning as modifiers in noun phrase structure are semantically similar to relative clauses: compare *any faults* [*that were identified in themselves*].

Past-participial modifiers are bare passives, as evident from the admissibility of a *by* phrase: *faults* [*identified in themselves by others*].

But they are not classified as some kind of relative clause, since there is no possibility of them containing a relative phrase: *faults which identified in* *themselves* is grammatical but it has a different meaning.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped a lot.